# How to implement startActivity() inside the OnClick() method of a separate Java class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

So i made three 3 java files.

1. main activity class
2. ButtonListener.java(Separate java class)
3. PurpleActivty.class(activity)

I implemented OnclickListener and OnClick method inside my ButtonListener.java file.

I want to start intent startActivity() inside my onClick(View v) of ButtonListener file. But it is throwing error on startActivity() line.

I know that i can make OnClick method under onCreate of AvtivityClass but i don't want to do this as i have made a separate java file that can handle all my button listeners.

**File MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   public Button intentPurple;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intentPurple=findViewById(R.id.button5);
       Intent gg= new Intent(MainActivity.this, PurpleActivty.class);
        ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener(gg);

        intentPurple.setOnClickListener(B);

    }

}
```

**file ButtonListener.java**

```
public class ButtonListener  implements View.OnClickListener {
     private Intent g;


    public ButtonListener(Intent F) {

        this.g=F;
    }
 @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {

                case R.id.button5:

          startActivity(g);  // this line is error(red underline g) error msg
           break;            //is "startActivity() in ContextCompat cannot be 
                            //applied to"
            }}}
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `startActivity` from the context of the activity, not from your custom handler class.  Refactor `ButtonListener` to this:

```
public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Intent g;
    private Context caller;

    public ButtonListener(Intent f, Context caller) {
        this.g = f;
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button5:
                caller.startActivity(g);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call your listener like this:

```
intentPurple = findViewById(R.id.button5);
Intent gg = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PurpleActivty.class);
ButtonListener b = new ButtonListener(gg, MainActivity.this);
intentPurple.setOnClickListener(b);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, would you recommend making a separate class for activtyStart(); or should i declare it inside my oncreate method of mainActivity class? i mean i can still make onClickListener inside my onCreate method

Comment: @EslaBaeny Not sure what you are asking.  You may want to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in

```
public ButtonListener(Intent F) {

    this.g=F;
}
```

you dont have to use this, because the variable names are different.
Other than that I believe the

```
 Intent gg= new Intent(**MainActivity.this**, PurpleActivty.class);
```

MainActivity.this is causing the issue as you are in a different class, you should pass MainActivity´s context as a parameter too and use

```
 context.startActivity(g);
```

OR

```
view.getContext().startActivity(g);
```

Comment: public ButtonListener(Intent F) is to pass the intent obj value into constructor of  public ButtonListener without it ButtonListener wont get intent obj value to start Startactivity(obj)

Comment: context.startActivity(openThree)... what you mean by openThree?

Comment: by "you dont have to use this" I didnt mean you dont have to use the constructor, but they keyword this itself.